# TailWindCSS Max Height (Pre Vers 3.0)

Tags: css, media-queries, tailwind-css

So I want to know how to set a Max Height Media Breakpoint in TailWindCSS Config.
IPad Pro's are recognised as Laptops because of their width.
That said, they are far too tall for Laptop CSS, making my site look horrible.

Any help welcome,
Thanks,
Justin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spit through the Tailwind docs, it seems like there are **none for Max Height** media queries.

But you can create your own [Custom media queries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/#custom-media-queries). I don't known the height of an iPad Pro. But I made an example based on the docs. (Also untested example)

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'iPad': {'raw': '(max-height: 1234px)'},
        // => @media (max-height: 1234px) { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
I'm not sure what the output of this will be, my guess `iPad:text-xl` or something.

Comment: Thanks for looking dude! I saw the screens option in the config but I didn't know you can specify height. Have a brilliant day! :)

Comment: For anyone who is interested this is the code for an iPad Pro ~Only~:
`iPadPro: {'raw': '(width: 1024px) and (height: 1366px)'},`.
(Tested via CodePen and it seems to work.)

Comment: Here is a snippet that essentially forces iPadPros to be a Tablet rather than Laptop Screen :   
md: {'raw': '(max-width: 768px), (width: 1024px) and (height: 1366px)'},
Seems to work on CodePen so should be good to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep! You could use an arbitrary variant, [@media(max-height:953px)]:top-[34%] or you could have it as a screen value in your Tailwind configuration:

```
screens: {
  foo: {
    raw: '(max-height: 953px)'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo:top-[34%]">
```

```html
<div class="[@media(max-height:953px)]:top-[34%] foo:top-[34%]">
```

Also you can do something like

```html
<div class="[@media_((min-height:940px)_and_(min-width:1800px))]:top-[34%] foo:top-[34%]">
```

Answered [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/12788#discussioncomment-8189826)

Comment: Hey Nikita; great answer thank you for this one! This post was made long before arbitrary values was a thing in Tailwindcss. For anyone visiting this in future I'd recommend looking at alternative solutions like the one above; for now I'll add a version number to the question to keep this as a bit of a time capsule.